# How to make YouTube search results to be of webm format in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, youtube, html5, webm

In Google Chrome there is an extension that add `&webm=1` in all YouTube search URIs. I did not find an alternative add-on in Firefox, any alternative methods? Thanks.

Comment: And I do not want to add the code manually, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag this:

```
javascript:void(location.href=location.href+"&webm=1")
```

to your bookmarks toolbar or add a new bookmark with it as the url.

And when you're on a youtube video page just click it in the toolbar or bookmark menu.

This will simply add the requested text onto the end of any URL currently in the address bar, and attempt to go there

Comment: The solution is good, but I always hide the bookmarks bar...